# Compile without input

Tags: c, gcc, sh

I'm trying to use **GCC** in a shell script, but i want to use no input file, but a variable that contain my code.

For now I do :

```
echo '
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int a=1,b;
  printf("Donnez un nombre : ");
  scanf("%d", &b);
  a+=b;
  printf("test%d\n",a );
  return 0;
}
' > .temp.c
#Entrez le texte ici

gcc .temp.c -o .ex -std=c99
```

Can I do something like `gcc $inputCode -o executable` ?
Moreover, if someone know if I can execute this c code without generating any file ?
Thanks !

Comment: did you try `gcc - -o .ex -std=c99` ? In other programs, you can use `-` to indicate "read-from-std-in". Good luck.

Comment: Look at http://tinycc.org

Comment: Thanks @shellter it work pretty well, but I had to add `-x c` to precise my code is in c. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do: `echo whatever | gcc -x c -o .ex -` but I hardly think it's worth it.

An alternate that may be cleaner [you don't have do either `\"` or `\'`].  Note that the `trap` example may not be completely correct, but is probably something you're trying to achieve.

```
cat << EOF | gcc -x c -o .ex -
int
main(void)
{
    return 'a';
}
EOF
trap "rm -f .ex" SIGINT
.ex
rm -f .ex
```

But, you're *still* going to have to create an output ELF executable *file*.  Partly because the OS needs the embedded ELF loader (e.g. `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`) to know how to load the executable.

I've done the "script creates C executable from source" many times and I just create the .c and the executable and just do `rm` afterwards.  I do this in `perl` where the C text appears after `__DATA__` and I do an `unlink` function call instead of `rm`